I need help in understanding why the probability of selecting an urn is not considered as $\frac{1}{2}$ in this question
There are two boxes A and B. A contains 3 red balls and 4 black balls and B contains 5 black balls. One ball is transferred from the box A to the box B without seeing the colour. Now, two balls are drawn, one from each box. What is the probability that both the balls are black?

My approach:
Case 1: When red ball is transferred
Urn A will have 2 Red, 4 Black and Urn B will have 1 Red and 5 Black balls
Probability of selecting urn A = $\frac{1}{2}$
Probability of getting black ball = $\frac{4}{6}$
Probability of selecting urn B = $\frac{1}{2}$
Probability of getting black ball = $\frac{5}{6}$
So, probability in this case will be $\frac{5}{36}$
Similarly, for Case 2: When black ball has been transferred
Urn A will have 3 Red, 3 Black and Urn B will have 6 Black balls
$\frac{1}{2}$ * $\frac{3}{6}$ * $\frac{1}{2}$ * 1
What is wrong with my approach ?

As per official answer, probability of selecting the urn is not $\frac{1}{2}$, rather it is something else, I am not able to understand this bit


You aren't selecting an urn. You take one ball from each urn.

Can you edit your question to make it explicit where you are getting your numbers from? It isn’t clear to me

OP: Maybe you can describe where you think an urn is being selected. Like @lulu, I only see balls being selected from urns.

thanks @lulu, i get the point now that we dont need probability of selecting the urn because the event is already defined in question of picking one ball from each urn, but then this 3/7 and 4/7 probabilities are not making sense to me.  What do thse probabilities indicate if not choosing the urn ?

Those are the probabilities of transferring a red (resp. black) ball.

There are two cases:  Case 1:  A red ball was taken from urn A and put in urn B.  Case 2: A black was taken for urn A and put in urn B.  But these two cases are not equally likely to happen.  Case 1 has a $\frac {3\text{ red balls}}{7\text{ total balls}}=\frac 37$ of having happened.  And Case 2 has a $\frac {4\text{ black balls}}{7\text{ total balls}}=\frac 47$ of having happened. You have to take into account the probabilities of cases in figuring the total probability of two read balls.  Otherwise what are you expected to do with the two cases.

Which urn you choose in each step is not left to chance here, it is clearly stated. You know from which urn you choose to transfer the one ball to another - from A to B, so no need to count probabilities like what urn is chosen. The same in the second case: it is clearly stated that you choose one ball from each urn. So nothing left to chance here as well.
If the task would have been stated as follows: an urn is chosen at random and from that urn a ball is drawn, what is the probability of it being black, — then you would consider the probability of choosing one urn over the other.
I recommend you try to understand the solution line by line and what the numbers in it mean.
Update: In the first step, you are choosing a random ball from urn A and putting it into B. The urn A contains 3 red and 4 black, so 7 balls in total. The probability of drawing a red ball from it is 3/7. That means, this is the probability that you will end up with 2 red & 4 black balls in A, and 1 red & 5 black balls in B.
Question for you: What is the probability of choosing a black ball from B after such transfer? —> 5/6. And what is the probability of choosing a black ball from A in such case? —> 4/6.
What about the case when we transfer a black ball from A to B?

Thank you for the answer, I understand that we will not take probabilites of selecting Urn A and Urn B, but then what are these 3/7 and 4/7 probabilites ? what are they indicating , iam not able to understand... I earlier thought that these meant the probabilities of selecting urn, but if its not that , then what exactly are they indicating ?

Answered in the update above.

Take a look at the course introduction to probability and statistics from mit open courseware: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-05-introduction-to-probability-and-statistics-spring-2022/pages/classes-reading-and-in-class-materials/
